# UNIX commands from R via shell function

Tags: r, bash, rstudio, knitr, git-bash

I need to issue unix commands from an R session. I'm on Windows R2 2012 server using RStudio 1.1.383 and R 3.4.3.

The `shell()` function looks to be the right one for me but when I specify the path to my bash shell (from Git for Windows install) the command fails with error code 127.

```
shell_path <- "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"
shell("ls -a", shell = shell_path)
## running command 'C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe /c ls -a' had status 127'ls -a' execution failed with error code 127
```

Pretty sure my shell path is correct:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: for clarity I would like to pass any number of UNIX commands, I am just using `ls -a` for an example.

EDIT:

After some playing about 2018-03-09:

`shell(cmd = "ls -a", shell = '"C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe"', intern = TRUE, flag = "-c")`

The correct location of my bash.exe was at `.../bin/bash.exe`. This uses `shell` with `intern = TRUE` to return the output as an R object. Note the use of single quote marks around the shell path.

EDIT: 2018-03-09 21:40:46 UT

In RStudio we can also call bash using `knitr` and setting chunk options:

`library(knitr)`

````
```{bash my_bash_chunk, engine.path="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"}
# Using a call to unix shell
ls -a
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things stand out here. Bash will return exit code 127 if a command is not found; you should try running the fully qualified command name.

I also see that your shell is being run with a `/c` flag. [According to the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/shell), the `flag` argument specifies "the switch to run a command under the shell" and it defaults to `/c`, but "if the shell is bash or tcsh or sh the default is changed to '-c'." Obviously this isn't happening for `git-bash.exe`.

Try these changes out:

```
shell_path <- "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"
shell("/bin/ls -a", shell = shell_path, flag = "-c")
```

Not on Windows, so can't be sure this will work.

Comment: Apologies. Yes and with fully qualified `"/bin/ls -a"

Comment: What happens if you just try something that uses a shell built-in like `echo foo` instead of running `ls`?

Comment: You could also try `system2(command=shell_path, args=c("-c", shQuote("/bin/ls -a")))`

Comment: `echo ...` gave error code 127. `system2(...` spawned a brief shell session that closed without returning a result to R console

Comment: Then that 127 is probably happening as a result of trying to run git-bash.exe itself; sorry can't help you out.

Comment: correct location for shell exe was `.../bin/bash.exe`. Using `shell` with this gave output from bash commands.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use `shQuote`?

```
shell( paste("ls -a  ", shQuote( shell_path) ) )
```

(Untested. I'm not on Windows. But do read `?shQuote`))

Comment: OP isn't looking to get a directory listing _of_ git-bash.exe, wants a directory listing _using_ it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do `ls -a`, you can use the below commands:

```
shell("'ls -a'", shell="C:\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe")

#or
shell('C:\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe -c "ls -a"')
```

Let us know if the space in "Program Files" is causing problems.

And if you require login before you can call your command,

```
shell('C:\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe --login -c "ls -a"')
```

But if you are looking at performing git commands from R, the `git2r` by ropensci might suit your needs.

Comment: my sh.exe is located @ "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe". Still get error code 127 with all these code chunks. I'm not interested in git commands - just have bash on my windows machine from Git for Windows install. I wondered about the space character but haven't seen that flagged as a problem in other SO posts on the subject and \\ing the space out makes no difference.

Comment: Maybe you want to try use the ~ form for program files? Can rem off top of my head. You will need to google. I have git in my c drive and the above works for me 64bit r3.3.2 win7.